# message id went wrong when using CEF devtools ExecuteDevToolsMethodAsync and Page.captureScreenshot

Tags: c#, devtools, chromium-embedded

I have added a CEF control into a WinForm. And I have added an `invokeCapture` method that is expected to capture the screen shot of the entire page of the CEF. It works fine when first invoking. But errors are encountered since second invoking and more, which the message is "Generated MessageID 100002 doesn't match returned Message Id 100001". How can I capture screen shot more than once?

I have copied the screenshot function code from https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/DevTools/DevToolsExtensions.cs to my project and renamed the namespace of it to `winformcefdemo.CefSharp.Example`.

The variable `lastMessageId` of the class `DevToolsClient`, in which class `CaptureScreenshot` executes `ExecuteDevToolsMethodAsync` in order to run command "Page.CaptureScreenshot", is private and there are either no getter nor setter to it. It seems to be annoying. The method `ExecuteDevToolsMethodAsync` would want to compare the message ID of what the method `ExecuteDevToolsMethod` returns to the automatically increased message ID of  the `DevToolsClient` itself. The `DevtoolsClient` in the method `CaptureScreenShotAsPng` is what `browser.GetDevToolsClient()` returns (in the line 36 of the link above). And I have also checked the implementation of the method `GetDevToolsClient`. It is also using `DevToolsClient devToolsClient = new DevToolsClient(browser);` in `CefSharp.DevToolsExtensions`.

```cs
        private async void invokeCapture()
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] result = await winformcefdemo.CefSharp.Example.DevTools.DevToolsExtensions.CaptureScreenShotAsPng(browser);
            
                // task.Start();
                // byte[] result = task.Result;
                SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                DialogResult dresult = dialog.ShowDialog();
                if (dresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string path = dialog.FileName;
                    try
                    {
                        File.WriteAllBytes(path, result);
                        MessageBox.Show(path + " saved success");
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(path + "Unknown error occurred when saving to file: " + e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unknown error occurred when capturing: " + ee.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in Chinese community of CSDN

Use no `DevToolsExtensions`. Use `PageClient` Instead. `DevToolsExtensions` does have issues that are not solved.

And `PageClient` should be defined **globally**. Do not define it in the method.

```cs
        # Source: https://bbs.csdn.net/topics/398544662
        CefSharp.DevTools.Page.PageClient pageClien= null;
        private async void invokeCapture()
        {
           if(pageClien==null)
            {
                pageClien =  webBrowser.GetBrowser().GetDevToolsClient().Page;
            }

            var result = await pageClien.CaptureScreenshotAsync();
            
            if (result.Data != null)
            {

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(result.Data);
                ms.Write(result.Data, 0, result.Data.Length);

                SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                dialog.Filter = "PNG Picture (*.PNG)|*.PNG";
                DialogResult dresult = dialog.ShowDialog();
                if (dresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string path = dialog.FileName;
                    try
                    {
                        File.WriteAllBytes(path, result);
                        MessageBox.Show(path + " saved success");
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(path + "Unknown error occurred when saving to file: " + e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This issue should have been resolved in version 87.1.132, upgrading to a newer version would be my recommendation.

Comment: @amaitland Tried the version 87 but the same exception occurred even on the first screenshot . "Generated MessageId 2 doesn't match returned Message Id 1". Both two paragraphs of code have the issue.

Comment: Your welcome to submit a PR with a unit test that reproduces the problem, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/88/CefSharp.Test/DevTools/DevToolsClientFacts.cs#L128 has a unit test you can use as the basis.

Comment: @amaitland the PR is submitted to the ```master``` branch. Just check it out.  [https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/3427](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/3427)